# Looping through an array and displaying items when they meet certain conditions

Tags: java

I don't know why this is taking me so long to figure out, but I have an ArrayList of HashMaps that I want to loop through. The looping through part  is easy and I know how to do it, but I only want to display items when they meet certain conditions.

Here is an example of the contents inside my `HashMap<String, String>`:

```
post_type="Facebook" 
post_type="Facebook" 
post_type="Twitter"
```

Here is the code I tried to loop through the above contents. When it prints, it only prints one line instead of two.

```
    for (int i=0; i < newArray.size(); i++)
    {
        String postType = newArray.get(i).get("type"); 

        if (postType.equals("Facebook")){ 
            System.out.println("HELLO"); // i want this to print twice, but it only prints once, even though there are two elements of type Facebook in the HashMap
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are filling it correctly?

Comment: post the code where you add this hashmap to arraylist

Comment: @Christian yes, i'm sure. if I do println on postType, it prints out the correct info.

Comment: `post_type` is the key or the value?

Comment: @Christian it is the key

Comment: he deleted the answer :P@Christian

Comment: So what happens when you and an else to that conditional to show what the other values are?

Comment: Try adding `System.out.prinln(postType);` above your if statement

Comment: How do you add elements to newArray? Show the code.

Comment: If post_type is the key won't hashmap override previous value with the new value in case of duplicate key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to maintain something like

```
Map<String,ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
```

to maintain multiple values for single key.
Key in your case is "post_type" and value is Facebook, Facebook, Twitter

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, this

```
String postType = newArray.get(i).get("type");
```

Should be

```
String postType = newArray.get(i).get("post_type");
```

Because

> ... I have an `ArrayList` of `HashMap`s ... Here is an example of the contents inside my `HashMap<String, String>`:
>
> ```
> post_type="Facebook" 
> post_type="Facebook" 
> post_type="Twitter"
> ```

And, `type` is not `post_type`.